# The upwardly closed subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading the book Probabilistic Graphical Models (Koller and Friedamn). I'm not quite sure about this example:

Given the next graph:

[image]

The updwardly closed subgraph K+[C] is:

[image]

I don't get it. I understand why nodes A and D are present but why B and E? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Definition of upwardly closed subgraph

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a definition for **upwardly closed subgraph** from the book you're using?

Comment: @PaddlingGhost Sure.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be standard terminology, no?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about: $\mathcal{K}^+[Y]$.  Given a set $Y$ of vertices, $\mathcal{K}^+[Y]$ consists of all those vertices that are either on the boundary of $Y$ or on the boundary of a vertex in the boundary of $Y$.  That is, start with $Y$ and then include all those vertices that are either parents of or adjacent (non-directedly) to any of the vertices in $Y$.  Then include all those vertices that are either parents of or adjacent (non-directedly) to any of your included vertices.  This gives you $\mathcal{K}^+[Y]$.

In the given example:  $\mathcal{K}^+[C]$ consists of those vertices on the boundary of $C$, so $A$ and $D$, and it consists of all those vertices on the boundary of any of those vertices.  So, we also include $E$, and $B$ is on the boudnary of $E$, so all together $\mathcal{K}^+[C]$ is the subgraph induced by the set $\{A,C,D,E,B\}$, as the example indicates.

Comment: If $H$ was also connected to $E$ meaning it would be a neighbour of the node $E$, would it also be a part of boundary of $C$, such as $K^{+}[C]$?